# What are the possible events for amp-story?

Tags: events, amp-html, amp-story

Is there one place to see all of the events for amp-story, events in the pipeline, and events that are never going to go live?

**sample topics**

- clipboard events
- drag events
- mouse events
- keyboard events
- window event attributes
- form events
- media events
- miscellaneous events such as ontoggle, which fires in HTML5 when the user opens or closes the  element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think such a list exists, but there are not currently any events that publishers can hook into, nor are there any pending.

You can always file a feature request with any specific use cases you might have.